# Inspiron lockup and won't shutdown

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, shutdown, inspiron

I have just finished installing Kubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 series laptop. When I shutdown that it run (if I don't press power off then it runs forever) like this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BjnJ.jpg]

If anyone knows how to fix this error, please tell me.

Comment: Where is the picture?

Comment: Please attach the picture and add some more details in your question.